# Is there a way to open a BS collapse through a link?

Tags: css

If I have a simple BS collapse:

```
<a href="#content-<?php echo id; ?>" data-toggle="collapse">Trigger Text</a>

<div id="content-<?php echo id; ?>" class="collapse">
Content...
</div>
```

Is it possible to trigger the toggle to open as it goes to it from a link in a separate module?

Say link would be:

```
https://website/article#content-83
```

It's already going to where content #83 is located at the article, but since the toggle is set to closed on that page it only goes to the article page and never actually shows the contents of content #83. There are reasons it needs to be closed on the page it shows up on, but not if clicked through from that link.

Comment: So before the content is displayed, you want to have a plugin conditionally remove the class="collapse" attribute? or would you like to change the value from collapse to something else? This, of course, would be a "conditional" action whereby only the id value matches the fragment value. Relevant reading: [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2317508/2943403)

Comment: I've never made a plugin, but if that would help I can give it a shot. Just need the collapse to open when accessed through that link. The content is JComments comments. I have them collapsed with certain info on toggles, but it screwed up the link in the latest comments module so that when you click comment #83 it just takes you to the article and stops, so you still have to look through the toggles to find #83 and then manually open it, where if it automatically opened it you wouldn't have to search for it and open it, you would just know where it is because it's the only one open.

Comment: The system has bumped this page because it is not deemed resolved by the system.  Did you manage to resolve this with Sharky's answer?  By yourself?  Or is it not yet resolved?  Please progress this page by accepting or answering or editing your question.

Comment: No, moved on. Haven't tried the new solution, but since there's already an a tag that opens the collapse on the page i'm not sure how or where to work that in.

Comment: the system has bumped this question again for new attention since it is not deemed to be resolved.  Can you please progress this page toward a system-recognised resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Get the fragment from URL, check that element with the same ID is collapsible and run `collapse('show')` if it is:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var fragment = window.location.hash;
    if (fragment && jQuery(fragment).hasClass('collapse')) {
        jQuery(fragment).collapse('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Where would that go? Keep getting errors anyplace I put it.

Comment: This is JavaScript code. You can add it to your template (either inline or in a .js file) or to layout override. Or load it with a plugin. Related documentation: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page and https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript.

Comment: I got it working, but it only opens the toggle for a few seconds and then immediately it closes again.

Comment: @Mythic I suppose rather than changing the attribute value, you could remove the class so that it "doesn't get pickup again" by another js function.  (if this answer was helpful to you, please upvote; if it resolves your issue, please accept)

Comment: Can't do that or they all just stay open. Does seem like something is overriding it at the end though. Tried finding a place where it would be last to run, but no such luck yet.

Comment: Sorry I haven't accepted the answer yet because it does indeed open the bootstrap collapse, but it should also stay open. I feel like this is half of the answer. I'm thinking I need to put a condition around the div where the collapse selection ("collapse" or "collapse in") appears and somehow have the js pass the fragment to the php, then have the php run a separate div code when the comment ids line up.

Comment: It looks like mickmack's first link will help, just have to sort it out.The way I have it set up there are also 2 toggles, one for the comments themselves and one for replies. This method only opens the top level comments, the reply level comments may open and close as well but you can't see them because the replies toggle is closed. Passing a variable to php for the comment id could let me do a query and get the parent id to also open that other toggle for replies to open on click as well.

Comment: You can always test this by opening firefox developer tools and then pasting it into the console. If it works then something else on the page is interfering (Chrome, etc will have similar developer tools).

Answer (score 0):

In case you have something else triggered by the click that opens the collapse, this will work as well:

```
 $('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').click();
```

The thing you need to watch for in doing either of these approaches is javascript load order. It's always possible jQuery may not have loaded by this time (in which case you'll get an error about '$') or in noConflict mode (try again replacing '$' with 'jQuery') or that the collapse plug-in hasn't loaded yet (when the call to 'collapse()' will toss a null object/method error). Javascript is funny that way, especially when attributes like 'async' are added to script tags because Google says that makes the page load faster.